# How to know which java files are the cause of a gradle dependency

Tags: gradle, gradlew

I have a gradle project A which has module1 and module2. Module1 is dependent upon module2.
I want to know which java class in module2 is causing the dependency.

Comment: Just remove the dependency, then you'll see which classes won't compile anymore. Only works for hard dependencies though.

Comment: This approach cannot be applied to big projects.

Comment: What is your actual goal? Do you want to remove unused dependencies, or refactor modules? If it is the former, then there are plugins that do that.

Comment: Is there some of this that can't be accomplished by running `./gradlew dependencies` on `project A`?  It should give you a fairly thorough tree to show which dependency is coming from where.  [Gradle Docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html)

Comment: @User51 yes I tried it but it does not give class file level information. it only goes till jar. do you have any option which can be used to get java class level info?

Comment: @LeonardBrünings I was looking for an inbuilt option but yes, if you know plugin that will also be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to find unused dependencies, you can try https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.autonomousapps.dependency-analysis. The name is a bit misleading as it also works fine for non-android projects. It gives recommendations how to improve your dependencies, one of those is to removed unused dependencies.

Comment: Thanks, this is nice. Adding the github link https://github.com/autonomousapps/dependency-analysis-android-gradle-plugin